# nonlocal keyword is giving error in python

Tags: python

```
class Solution(object):
    def isValidBST(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        bst=1
        def left(cur,traverse):
            if cur:  
                traverse.append(cur.val)
                traverse=left(cur.left,traverse)
                traverse=left(cur.right,traverse)
            return traverse
        def find(cur):
            nonlocal bst
            l=max(left(cur.left,[]))
            r=min(left(cur.right,[]))
            print(l,r,cur.val)
            if l>cur.val:
                nonlocal bst
                bst=0
                return
            if r<cur.val:
                nonlocal bst
                bst=0
                print(bst)
                return
            if cur.left:
                find(cur.left)
            if cur.right:    
                find(cur.right)
        cur=root
        
        find(cur)  
        print(bst)
        if bst==0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

This is a leetcode question to validate binary search tree.
The above code is giving error for nonlocal keyword as invalid syntax , What is reason ?
but for the following code it is not showing any mistake

```
def gen():
    d=56
    def fun():
        nonlocal d
        d=70
        return
    fun()
    print(d)
    
gen()
```

Comment: I think you want to just leave out the `nonlocal` in the if statements.

Comment: `nonlocal`  just needs once per variable. Recommend right next line of the function name. The test on my end shows python confused the order of using `bst=0` and the second usage of `nonlocal`.

Comment: bst has already been declared nonlocal just after def find(cur) and can be used throughout this nested function without further declaration (as commented by @user_na)